# Hyperledger 1.4 install & instantiate javascript chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Im trying to install & instantiate a javascript chaincode app. Im using the fabcar demo app.

Install works fine:

```
peer chaincode install -l node -n fabcar -v 1.1.1 -p hyperledger-config/chaincode/src/fabcar/ -o orderer0-service:7050 --tls --cafile=/etc/hyperledger/orderers/msp/tlscacerts/ca-root-7054.pem

2020-03-09 20:11:20.003 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2020-03-09 20:11:20.003 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
2020-03-09 20:11:20.032 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 003 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
```

Chaincode instantiation is where it fails with an error Im not able to find information about

```
peer chaincode instantiate -C mainchannel -n fabcar -l node -v 1.1.1 -c '{"Args":[]}' -o orderer0-service:7050 --tls --cafile=/etc/hyperledger/orderers/msp/tlscacerts/ca-root-7054.pem -P "AND('org1.admin', 'org2.admin')"
2020-03-09 20:11:50.142 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2020-03-09 20:11:50.142 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: npm: not found
"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed node package manager(NPM)? If yes what's the version of NPM? The error clearly specifies that the script file can't find npm. Don't forget to add it to the path. Find the installation guide [here](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm).

Comment: Hi Aditya, where should I install NPM? On all the peers or the cli? I thought the peer hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4.3 image included all necessary software to install chaincode in any of the supported languages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded peers to 2.0 and now instantiation works as well.